# isset($_SESSION['id']) is not working properly

Tags: php, session

I am trying to use the condition:

> isset($_SESSION['id'])

So i just tried

> echo isset($_SESSION['id']); and echo $_SESSION['id'];

But this gives output different. In fact true result gives by

> echo $_SESSION['id'];

Any one have idea why this is happening?

**Note:** I use `session_start();` at the beginning of page.

Comment: `echo isset($_SESSION['id']); and echo $_SESSION['id'];` this is not valid PHP.

Comment: So do you expect us to guess your results?

Comment: Show us your actual code.

Comment: @Daan it's just a bad formatting, i think

Comment: [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) why is it always the LAST thing people look at

Comment: @Daan bt `isset($_SESSION['id'])` outputs 1

Comment: @yank Yes it returns `true` I know. But the `and echo $_SESSION['id']` gives a fatal error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isset is used in if condition, in case you want to check if session is set or not:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) { // check if session named 'id' is exist
       echo $_SESSION['id'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: I tried `echo isset($_SESSION['id'])` output 1 and i try`echo $_SESSION['id']` but output 4. If i use ur code then it will allow if `$_SESSION['id'] = 1`

Comment: isset will just check the existance of session named "id"..it will not check 1 or 0